# Pandas - conditionally concat two columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Given a dataframe

```
Patient ID     Instructions    ID Replaced
   1                N/A           ID123
   2                              ID124
   3                              ID125
   4                xyz           ID126
   5                xyz           ID127
   6                              ID128
   7                Replacement   ID129
   8                Replace       ID130
   9                replaced      ID131
   10               xyz           ID132
```

How can I make a new column, which concats `Instructions` with `ID Replaced` if `replac` substring is found?

```
Patient ID  Instructions    ID Replaced     Comments
    1           N/A            ID123    
    2                          ID124    
    3                          ID125    
    4           xyz            ID126    
    5           xyz            ID127    
    6                          ID128    
    7           Replacement    ID129    Replacement | ID129
    8           Replace        ID130    Replace | ID130
    9           Replaced       ID131    Replaced | ID131
    10          xyz            ID132
```

I've tried the following but the `Comments` column is completely empty

```
mani_df['Comments'] = ""
# if instructions contains 'replac' , concat with ID replaced 
if "replace" in df['Instructions']:
    df['Comments'] = df['Instructions'].str.cat(df['ID Replaced'], sep = " | ")
```

and I tried to use a boolean mask but this returns False for the first two rows

```
mask = mani_df['Special Handling Directions'].str.contains('replac')

    Out[55]: 
    0    False
    1    False
    2      NaN
    3      NaN
```

Comment: `if "replace" in df['Instructions']`: "replace" is not a value in the series `df['Instruction']`, so that `if` clause isn't gotten excecuted. You need something like `df['Instruction'].str.contains('replace')`, which give you a boolean mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use`str.contains` with `case=False` and just concat using `pandas indexing`

```
mask = df.Instructions.str.contains('Replace', case=False).fillna(False)

df['Comments'] = df.loc[mask, 'Instructions'] + ' | ' + df['ID Replaced']
```

Of course, you can `fillna` at the end to get empty strings (which looks like your expected output)

```
df.fillna('')
```

Yields

```
    Patient ID  Instructions    ID Replaced Comments
0   1                           ID123   
1   2                           ID124       
2   3                           ID125       
3   4           xyz             ID126   
4   5           xyz             ID127   
5   6                           ID128       
6   7           Replacement     ID129       Replacement | ID129
7   8           Replace         ID130       Replace | ID130
8   9           replaced        ID131       replaced | ID131
9   10          xyz             ID132
```

Comment: as a follow-up question, is there an easy way to alter this to an `if else`? Specifically, if the `mask` is `FALSE`, copy just the value in `Instructions` to `Comments` for that row?

Comment: Nevermind, ending up writing the mask to a column, creating a copy of the Comments column and comparing. Thanks agian!