# Best/Concise Way to Conditionally Concat two Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to conditionally concat two columns in a Pandas DataFrame.

I found one related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119307/pandas-conditionally-concat-two-columns), which I adapted below - but it seems like there should be a more concise way to do this.  In R with dplyr or data.table, this is a relatively simple line of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Product": ["Shorts", "T-Shirt", "Jacket", "Cap"],
        "Color": ["Red", "Blue", "White", "Green"],
        "Size": ["S", "M", None, "S"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

# if size = 'S' then concatenate Product and Color, else just Put in the value from Color column


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Size'] == 'S':
        df.loc[index, 'Output'] = str(row['Product']) + " (" + str(row['Color']) + ')'
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Output'] = str(row['Color'])
        
        
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is used to generate column values conditionally. First parameter is the condition, then the `True` values then the `False` values. In this case this can be something like:

```
df['Output'] = np.where(
    df['Size'].eq('S'),  # Condition
    df['Product'].astype(str) + df['Color'].map(' ({})'.format),  # Where True
    df['Color']  # Where False
)
```

`df`:

```
   Product  Color  Size        Output
0   Shorts    Red     S  Shorts (Red)
1  T-Shirt   Blue     M          Blue
2   Jacket  White  None         White
3      Cap  Green     S   Cap (Green)
```

Note: [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) was used with a format string because this can be faster as it produces less copies than multiple string concatenation, but it can also be done like:

```
df['Output'] = np.where(
    df['Size'] == 'S',
    df['Product'].astype(str) + ' (' + df['Color'].astype(str) + ')',
    df['Color']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also just a one-liner using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, mutate, if_else, paste0
>>> data = {"Product": ["Shorts", "T-Shirt", "Jacket", "Cap"],
...         "Color": ["Red", "Blue", "White", "Green"],
...         "Size": ["S", "M", None, "S"]}
>>> df = tibble(**data)
>>> df >> mutate(Output=if_else(f.Size == "S", paste0(f.Product, " (", f.Color, ")"), f.Color))
   Product    Color     Size        Output
  <object> <object> <object>      <object>
0   Shorts      Red        S  Shorts (Red)
1  T-Shirt     Blue        M          Blue
2   Jacket    White     None         White
3      Cap    Green        S   Cap (Green)
```

I am the author of datar, which is a python package backed by pandas to implement `dplyr`-like syntax in R.